# ajax:success callback doesn't fire after conversion from Coffeescript to ES6

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

I have some ajax Form on my page. 
I create a class to manage the behaviour of the buttons, and I have to change the class after the ajax success.

```
export class Following {
  constructor(element) {
    element  = $(element);

    this.follow   = element.find('.follow');
    this.unfollow = element.find('.following');

    this.followForm   = this.follow.parents('form');
    this.unfollowForm = this.unfollow.parents('form');

    this.bindClicks();

  }

  bindClicks() {
    this.followForm.on('ajax:error', this.trySignIn);

    this.followForm.on('ajax:success', event => {
      console.log('follow success')
    });

    this.unfollowForm.on('ajax:success', event => {
      console.log('unfollow success')
    });
  }

  static init() {
    $('.follow-unfollow-buttons').each((i, el) => new Following($(el)));
  }
};
```

When I submit the form, the ajax call is a success, but I cannot intercept the callback. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I'm using jquery-ujs instead of rails-ujs